# Displaying Last login Date and Time in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have added code for displaying last login date and time in my website ( front end ).But it is displaying only as 26 minutes 9 sec etc But I need to display date and time in hours minutes and seconds format. Here is the code:

```
function user_last_login( $user_login, $user ) {
update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_login', time() );
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'user_last_login', 10, 2 );

function lastlogin() {
$last_login = get_the_author_meta('last_login');
$the_login_date = date('F j, Y g:i a', $last_login);
return $the_login_date;
}

add_shortcode('lastlogin','lastlogin');
```

Comment: First of all try to return `$last_login` without using `human_time_diff` inside the `lastlogin` function. You should see some integer like `1609432337`. Then use `date('H:m:s', $last_login)` to get the formatted time;

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky not getting you what to be changed

Comment: Probably you don't need to use `human_time_diff`, instead try `date`. Docs is here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky i have changed that it is displaying Last Update : 15:12:02  $last_login = get_the_author_meta('last_login');
$the_login_date = date('H:m:s', $last_login);

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky thanks its working fine now

Comment: Please improve date format according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php It might be `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky $the_login_date = date('F j, Y, g:i a', $last_login); added this but the date is showing as january 1 1970

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky i have mentioned the timezone as UTC

Comment: @Riley unable to get you.It will be helpful if you explain some clearly

Comment: @ntrtrusttesting123, ignore my comment. I misread what you were trying to display.

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky i have changed but the timezone is showing 7 hours difference

Comment: I have changed the query but it is showing the time difference as 7 hours

Comment: can anyone let me know whats the issue please tat would be helpful for me a lot

Comment: Anyone who can help me out on this

Answer (score 0):

```
function user_last_login( $user_login, $user ) {
 update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_login', date( current_time( 'timestamp' )) );
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'user_last_login', 10, 2 );
function lastlogin() {  
$last_login = get_the_author_meta('last_login');
$the_login_date = date('F j, Y, g:i a', $last_login);
return $the_login_date;
}
add_shortcode('lastlogin','lastlogin');
```