# Wordpress - User last login date shortcode not work

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, shortcode

I have this shortcode, it should show the last login date to users. The problem I find is that all other users are viewing my last login date and not their date.

Am I doing something wrong with the shortcode?

```
// Last Login Shortcode
function user_last_login( $user_login, $user ) {
update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_login', date( current_time( 'timestamp' )) );
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'user_last_login', 10, 2 );

function lastlogin() {  
$last_login = get_the_author_meta('last_login');
$the_login_date = date('F j, Y, g:i a', $last_login);
return $the_login_date;
}
add_shortcode('lastlogin','lastlogin');
```

Comment: I am not great at Wordpress, but I know it works with MySQL and PHP so it shouldn't be too difficult to pinpoint. To rule out things, did you check if the Database gets updated correctly? We need to find out if the issue is when you update or when you retrieve the information.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, the database is updated correctly. I also have other shortcodes that work well, which are based on returning information like your registration date, your last purchase and things like that.

Maybe it depends on `get_the_author_meta` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. I post the code for anyone who will be in the same problem as me. Also I extended the code, now you get both the current date of login and the date of last access before the current login.

I’m not very good with these things, I’m relatively new in php, wordpress and codes in general. I invite anyone to clean the code and make it shorter and easier if possible.

*Put the code below in the functions.php file of your child theme.*

```
// Function that set last login
add_action('wp_login', 'set_last_login', 0, 2);
function set_last_login($login, $user) {
    $user = get_user_by('login',$login);
    $time = current_time( 'timestamp' );
    $last_login = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login', 'true' );
    if(!$last_login) {
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login', $time );
    } else {
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login_prev', $last_login );
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login', $time );
    }
}

// Function that get last login
function get_last_login($user_id, $prev = null) {
    $last_login = get_user_meta($user_id);
    $time = current_time( 'timestamp' );
    if(isset($last_login['_last_login_prev'][0]) && $prev) {
        $last_login = get_user_meta($user_id, '_last_login_prev', 'true' );
    } else if(isset($last_login['_last_login'][0])){
        $last_login = get_user_meta($user_id, '_last_login', 'true' );
    } else {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, '_last_login', $time );
        $last_login = $last_login['_last_login'][0];
    }
    return $last_login;
}

// Shortcode 1
function last_login_date() {
    global $current_user;
    echo '<p>Last login date: '. date("j M Y - H:i", get_last_login ($current_user->ID, true)) . '</p>';
}
add_shortcode('lastlogin', 'last_login_date');

// Shortcode 2
function current_login_date() {
    global $current_user;
    echo '<p>Current: Login date: '. date("j M Y - H:i", get_last_login($current_user->ID)). '</p>';
}
add_shortcode('currentlogin', 'current_login_date');
```

**1.** Use **[lastlogin]** if you want to show the last login date (not the current one)

**2.** Use **[currentlogin]** if you want to show the current date with each new login.

**How to change date and time format**:
You can make the change to both shortcode 1 and shortcode 2. Edit `"j M Y - H:i"` as you like, here’s some useful info https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Sorry about the bad English

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification. It looks like you're using the wrong function.

`get_the_author_meta()` Retrieves the requested data of the **author** of the current post, so all the users are going to show the date of the author of the post if you use that function.

So in your case you need to use `get_user_meta()`

You can find info here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/

Try the solution, if it doesn't work we will dig further.

Comment: Ok, I replaced `get_the_author_meta()` with `get_user_meta()` and the situation seems to have changed. However now I always get the date January 1, 1970, 12:00 am. This does not change, I always receive the same value in any situation. I read around and it looks like it is shown when no login date is found.

Comment: @Manuel it will also occur, if what you feed into `date` as second parameter isn't a proper unix timestamp value to begin with. So what _does_ `$last_login` actually contain?

Comment: @CBroe forgive my ignorance, I’m new to this. I don’t really know what `$last_login ` actually means. I took the code from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65523261/displaying-last-login-date-and-time-in-wordpress and tried to insert it into my functions.php. It doesn’t work, though, and I was trying to figure out why.

Comment: What format does the date get stored in the database? Is it Unix timestamps or is it something more readable like a proper date format?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying this on **april 14 2022**. It displays **march 30 2022**